# How to determine path to user log in FTP (VSFTP)?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

How do I determine the path the user logs in on FTP (VSFTP)? The user should only be able to access a specific path via FTP.

For example: The user can access only the path /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT. How do I configure this?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Could you clarify? Also, [FTP Must Die](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie).

Comment: Are you asking how you can give users access to `/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT` or perhaps how you can `chroot` them there?

Comment: By "paste", I believe you actually mean "path". Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You this correct.

Comment: When the user enter the ftp, they access the path /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure your FTP server in chroot/jail environment.

edit /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.chroot_list
passwd_chroot_enable=yes
```

Now, to file /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.chroot_list simply add name of user user1.

Change your user default home directory or you can also bind your access path with home directory of user.

```
usermod -d /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT user1
```

or

```
mount --bind /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT /home/user1
```

/etc/init.d/vsftpd  restart